# Changing ledger line color and size using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

I am using QGIS 3.4.

I want to change the color and size of the ledger line when drawing an object in a line layer to make it more visible if the tracing-function works correct.

It's currently very thin and red. The dotted part is from the last set point to the cursor.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS 3.4.5, go to `Settings -> Options -> Digitizing`, you need to change line color and line width under `Rubberband`:

[image]

Using `Line width = 3` and Line color of Blue it becomes like this:

[image]